# How to print all nodes at the same level in one group?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am working on the LeetCode problem [102. Binary Tree Level Order Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, return *the level order traversal of its nodes' values*. (i.e., from left to right, level by level).

I want to print all nodes at a given level in one group. I have found a way to do this in this answer [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747605/4080322).

But this answer uses recursion while my code does not. I would like to know where I am going wrong in my approach.

For example given input : `[1,2,3,4,null,null,5]`

My output : `[[1],[4],[5]]`

Expected output: `[[1],[2,3],[4,5]]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}

    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
};


vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode *root) {
    deque<TreeNode *> queue;
    map<int, vector<int>> myMap;
    vector<vector<int>> retvector;
    vector<int> addvector;
    int level = 0;

    if (root != nullptr) {
        queue.push_back(root);
        addvector.push_back(root->val);
        //retvector.push_back(addvector);
        myMap.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(level, addvector));
    }

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        TreeNode *ptr = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        addvector.clear();


        if (ptr->left != nullptr) {
            addvector.push_back(ptr->left->val);
            queue.push_back(ptr->left);
        }

        if (ptr->right != nullptr) {
            addvector.push_back(ptr->right->val);
            queue.push_back(ptr->right);
        }

        if (!addvector.empty()) {
            //retvector.push_back(addvector);
            myMap.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(level, addvector));
            level++;
            addvector.clear();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        retvector.push_back(myMap[i]);
    }

    return retvector;
}

int main() {
    TreeNode root, left1, left2, right1, right2;

    left2 = TreeNode(4);
    left1 = TreeNode(2, &left2, nullptr);
    right2 = TreeNode(5);
    right1 = TreeNode(3, nullptr, &right2);
    root = TreeNode(1, &left1, &right1);

    vector<vector<int>> v = levelOrder(&root);

    for (auto &i: v) {
        for (auto &j: i)
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. The function you posted takes a `TreeNode*`, there must be more code that processes input `[1,2,3,4,null,null,5]` to construct the tree

Comment: You need to perform BFS for level order traversal, then store nodes based on their level.

Comment: you need not keep track of the `addvector` manually. Instead you can directly push to vector in the map: `myMap[level].push_back(root->val);` wont fix the issue but make your code much simpler

Comment: Stopped reading after all those data structures – vectors, map, deque... You are doing things too complex, all you need is one single *queue*: Place the root into that queue, then iterate until the queue gets empty as follows: pop one element from front, print it, push all children to the back of the queue. That's it...

Comment: Ah, well, the brackets – not too much difficult either: Add current depth to the nodes (root is 0, and for any node the children have one additional depth). Then on printing when depths changes add a closing and an opening bracket... Unless the tree is empty: Before you start iteration print one opening bracket and when finished one closing... (in addition to those surrounding all the levels at once).

Comment: Actually I do not need to take care of printing the brackets. `vector<vector<int>>` is needed to be returned (can't change function signature - it's a Leetcode problem that's why).

Comment: you can change whatever you like on the code. Don't rely on Leetcode for testing and debugging your code. Write a main, test, debug, in your own environment. Once you know it works you can place it in Leetcode.

Comment: Producing the vector of vectors is just all alike: On depth changing, start a new vector...

Comment: @Aconcagua Added main(). Not printing brackets right now but all nodes at same level should print on the same line.

Comment: Consider how much easier this would be if you included the level a node came from in the queue along with the node pointer itself. Then you could do you work based on the result pops rather than just before pushes.

Comment: Adding a complete example was a good step. Please update output and expected output to match the code you posted.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please explain your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a map, nor a queue, nor a level number.

Instead alternate with 2 vectors that have the nodes of 2 consecutive levels.

Also, in your logic, `addvector` can at the most have 2 entries, which shows why this approach cannot work.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<TreeNode *> parentLevel, childLevel;
        vector<vector<int>> retvector;
        vector<int> addvector;
        
        if (root != nullptr) {
            parentLevel.push_back(root);
        }
        
        while (!parentLevel.empty()) {
            addvector.clear();
            childLevel.clear();
            for (auto parent : parentLevel) {
                addvector.push_back(parent->val);
                if (parent->left != nullptr) {
                    childLevel.push_back(parent->left);
                }
                if (parent->right != nullptr) {
                    childLevel.push_back(parent->right);
                } 
            }
            retvector.push_back(addvector);
            parentLevel = childLevel;
        }

        return retvector;
    }
};
```

### Explanation

Let's take the example tree:

```
         1
        / \
       2   3
      /     \
     4       5
```

`parentLevel` starts out with `[1]` (actually the TreeNode having 1).

Then the outer loop starts, where the inner loop will take every node in that `parentLevel` vector and put its value in `addvector`. So in this iteration, `addvector` will be [1].

In the same process all direct children of these nodes are collected in `childLevel`, so there we will have the nodes `[2, 3]`.

The inner loop then finishes, and `addvector` is appended to the result. So `retvector` will be `[[1]]`.

Now the same should happen with the children, so we promote `childLevel` to be the `parentLevel` for the next iteration of the outer loop.

And so we start the next iteration of the outer loop with `parentLevel` having `[2, 3]`. Again, the corresponding values get pushed to an empty `addvector`, which will then have `[2, 3]`. At the same time `childLevel` gets populated with the child nodes `[4, 5]`.

The second iteration of the outer loop will end by extending `retvector` to `[[1],[2,3]]`, and so the process continues level by level...

Comment: Can you explain the logic please?

Comment: There's no problem with `clearing` the vector, `push_back` creates a copy anyway. *If* you use a new vector every time, then I'd recommend `push_back(std::move(addvector))` to avoid that unnecessary copy. Similarly: `parentLevel = std::move(childLevel)` – again avoids copy.

Comment: @Aconcagua, thank you for pointing that out. Updated. Dyvyanshy, I added an explanation.